# iterate and show the json data in the existing table - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am getting the jsonData which i want to iterate and show in the table2 which is displayed by hiding the table1 when user click on the submit button.The table2 has many rows(6 rows) but the jsonData i'm getting has 3 rows which i want to iterate and show in the first 3 rows of the table2 and remaining rows are empty in table2 as we are getting only 3 rows information in the jsonData.

Sample Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/OewuCrobeM2cznRgL5Lo?p=preview

Sample js code:

```
function submitData(){
   var flag = true;
   if(flag){
     //after getting the values from backend hide the table1 and show table2
     $("#table1").hide();
      $("#table2").show();
     var jsonData = [{"sid":"1023","spread":"3","loanType":"auto","comments":"Loan Approved"},
     {"sid":"1024","spread":"4","loanType":"car","comments":"Loan Approved"},
     {"sid":"1025","spread":"3","loanType":"auto","comments":"Loan Denied"}]

  //iterate and show the jsonData in the table2 which is shown after user click on submit button and hide the table1 and show table2
   } 
 }
```

Sample html code:

```
<table id="table1" border="1"> 

    <tr>
        <th>SID</th>
        <th>spread%</th>
        <th>LoanType</th>
         <th>Comments</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid1" value="100"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread1" value="6"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType1" value="Auto"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments1" value="autoLoan"></td>
     </tr> 
        <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid2" value="200"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread2" value="7"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType2" value="Car"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments2" value="carLoan"></td>
     </tr> 
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid3" value="300"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread3" value="6"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType3" value="Auto"></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments3" value="autoLoan"></td>
     </tr> 
</table> 

<table id="table2" border="1" style="display:none">

    <tr>
        <th>SIDTable2</th>
        <th>spread% Table2</th>
        <th>LoanType Table2</th>
         <th>Comments Table2</th> 
    </tr>

    <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid1" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread1" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType1" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments1" value=""></td>
     </tr>
         <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid2" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread2" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType2" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments2" value=""></td>
     </tr> 
         <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid3" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread3" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType3" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments31" value=""></td>
     </tr> 
         <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid4" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread4" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType4" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments4" value=""></td>
     </tr> 
         <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid5" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread5" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType5" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments5" value=""></td>
     </tr> 
         <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid6" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread6" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType6" value=""></td>
         <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments6" value=""></td>
     </tr> 

</table> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitData()">
```

Note: In my case, the table is existing and i want to iterate the jsonData object and display the values in the table. But i'm finding the examples which is dynamically creating the table and displaying the JSON data in the table which i cannot use in my existing code. Any inputs would be helpful..thanks.

Comment: Did you try anything? I don't see any logic to fetch the data in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are having a fixed table structure, you can directly iterate through `jsonData` and bind the data to table using `$.each` as below:

```
$.each(jsonData, function(key, val) {
    $('#table2 tr:eq('+[key + 1]+') td:eq(0) input').val(val.sid);
    $('#table2 tr:eq('+[key + 1]+') td:eq(1) input').val(val.spread);
    $('#table2 tr:eq('+[key + 1]+') td:eq(2) input').val(val.loanType);
    $('#table2 tr:eq('+[key + 1]+') td:eq(3) input').val(val.comments); 
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  submitData = function() {
    var flag = true;
    if (flag) {
      //after getting the values from backend hide the table1 and show table2
      $("#table1").hide();
      $("#table2").show();
      var jsonData = [{
          "sid": "1023",
          "spread": "3",
          "loanType": "auto",
          "comments": "Loan Approved"
        },
        {
          "sid": "1024",
          "spread": "4",
          "loanType": "car",
          "comments": "Loan Approved"
        },
        {
          "sid": "1025",
          "spread": "3",
          "loanType": "auto",
          "comments": "Loan Denied"
        }
      ];

      //iterate and show the jsonData in the table2 which is shown after user click on submit button and hide the table1 and show table2
      $.each(jsonData, function(key, val) {
        $('#table2 tr:eq(' + [key + 1] + ') td:eq(0) input').val(val.sid);
        $('#table2 tr:eq(' + [key + 1] + ') td:eq(1) input').val(val.spread);
        $('#table2 tr:eq(' + [key + 1] + ') td:eq(2) input').val(val.loanType);
        $('#table2 tr:eq(' + [key + 1] + ') td:eq(3) input').val(val.comments);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table1" border="1">

  <tr>
    <th>SID</th>
    <th>spread%</th>
    <th>LoanType</th>
    <th>Comments</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid1" value="100"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread1" value="6"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType1" value="Auto"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments1" value="autoLoan"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid2" value="200"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread2" value="7"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType2" value="Car"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments2" value="carLoan"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid3" value="300"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread3" value="6"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType3" value="Auto"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments3" value="autoLoan"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="table2" border="1" style="display:none">

  <tr>
    <th>SIDTable2</th>
    <th>spread% Table2</th>
    <th>LoanType Table2</th>
    <th>Comments Table2</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid1" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread1" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType1" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments1" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid2" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread2" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType2" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments2" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid3" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread3" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType3" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments31" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid4" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread4" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType4" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments4" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid5" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread5" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType5" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments5" value=""></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="sid" id="sid6" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="spread" id="spread6" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="loanType" id="loanType6" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="comments" id="comments6" value=""></td>
  </tr>

</table>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="submitData()">
```